# Deletion of Lightning Component Bundle (Managed)

Tags: managed-package, lightning

I have "**Managed Component Deletion feature**" activated on packaging org.

I need to delete Lightning Components from Managed Released version.

Tried 2 regular ways:

- dev console, the error is

> "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY"

- destructive changes, the error is

> "Error: cannot delete managed object"

How I can delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components) shows that lightning component can't be deleted, once they are part of Managed Release Package.

[image]

Comment: thanks, missed this last time checked the doc


** If the ability to remove components has been enabled for your packaging organization, you can delete these component types even if they are part of a Managed - Released package.